# Failed to load in Laravel/maatwebsite/excel when export excel file

Tags: php, excel, laravel

Developer!
I export excel from html view in Laravel/maatwebsite. It's going very well but if there have a "&" special character then occur an error. I find out it. But I couldn't solve it.
Please help me.
Error is like this.
PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception
Failed to load /home/***/****/storage/framework/cache/laravel-excel/laravel-excel-vRQ1Fp0mrWZjoXeFWJPGtI0M2DfylYeF.html as a DOM Document

I searched this problem in google but i didn't get any solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can probably add your file to get a clear understanding!